# OSH Park setup for KiCad

Tags: pcb, kicad, gerber

Anyone know the exact setup needed to send KiCad files to OSH Park? Specifically how to set the trace widths correctly?

Comment: The [specs](http://oshpark.com/pricing) say that minimum trace width is 6 mils.  Is the question "How to set my traces to 6/8/10 mils in KiCad"?

Comment: Actually the specs are quite a bit more than just that - clearances, edge of board rules, drill rules, etc!

Comment: Yes to both :P Mostly, what different do I have to do from EAGLE? I would use EAGLE, but my boards are too big for the free version and cannot afford the paid version.

Comment: Also see http://oshpark.com/guidelines

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure this is a good question for EE.SE, but here's how to do this in KiCad:

1. From the **Design Rules** menu select **Design Rules**
2. Choose the **Global Design Rules**. There you can modify available trace widths/vias.

The **Custom Track Widths** lists the available track widths (i.e. outside of those defined for specific net classes [see below]. And the custom via sizes lists lists all the vias you want to have available while routing.  Thus, in the following dialog box trace widths of 10 mils, 15 mils, 20 mils, and 32 mils are made available for selection while routing, but only one via size.

[image: KiCad Design Rules Editor]

You can also

- Set the vias/trace widths for specific net classes in the **Net Classes Editor** tab of the (**Design Rules**) dialog.  This is a PITA, however, since KiCad makes it a bit difficult to assign sensible names to net classes (as far as I know). You can, however, edit all the files by hand (all KiCad files are text files), so with some regular expressions, this might be a way to go.

After doing the initial setup, the second toolbar, on the left, will offer choices of trace widths and vias you can use for routing, as in the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I use this page to setup my KiCAD. This is OSH Park's own documentation for KiCAD.

[OSH Park design rules for KiCAD](http://docs.oshpark.com/design-tools/kicad/kicad-design-rules/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/104227)

Comment: @AdamHaun: Given that this is OSH Park's own reference material on the matter, it's a very good answer.

Comment: @DaveTweed Fair enough, I suppose.